# Laravel 4 many to many relationship error when no records match

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to build a messaging system. Where I have users and conversations with a many to many relationship.

User model:

```
public function conversations() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Conversation');
}
```

Conversation

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

I can get the user and the conversations the user is in with:

```
$user = User::with('conversations')->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

Or:

```
$user = User::with('conversations')->find(1);
```

The problem is that when the user does not have any conversations I get an exception:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: select * from 
`conversations` where `id` in ()) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

How can I test if the user has conversations to avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I create new conversations in the ConversationsController like so:

Updated the create method after David Barker's solution:

```
public function create($id)
{
    // Check user exists
    $user = User::find($id);
    if ( ! $user )
        throw new Exception('User not found');

    // Create a new conversation
    $conversation = new Conversation();
    $conversation->creator = Auth::user()->id;
    $conversation->save();

    // Attach the users to the conversation
    $conversation->users()->attach($user);
    $conversation->users()->attach(Auth::user());

    return $conversation;
}
```

But I still get the exception this way as well.

After walking away from the project for some hours I think this may be a possible solution:

```
$con = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->conversations; 

if(0 < $con->count()) {

    $conversationIds = array();
    foreach ($con as $conversation) {
        $conversationIds[] = $conversation->id;
    }

    // I THINK THIS WAS ACTUALLY THE PROBLEM
    $conversations = Conversation::with('users')->whereIn('id', $conversationIds)->get();

} else {
    $conversations = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post up the relationships you have in your models?

Comment: @DavidBarker I edited to include it at the top

Comment: And you have a pivot table `conversations_users`?

Comment: And can you confirm that you really want a many:many relationship?

Comment: @DavidBarker well the users can participate in multiple conversations and multiple users can participate in the same conversation, so yeah I guess, otherwise if I don't need many to many please explain why?

Comment: I'm not saying you don't need it, just wanted to make sure that's what you wanted. In that case can you confirm you have a pivot table that records the many to many relationships?

Comment: @DavidBarker yes I have a pivot table(conversation_user) with: id, user_id, conversation_id, created_at, updated_at. I can see in phpmyadmin that when conversations are being created the pivot table is being filled too with the correct values. I do have a working conversation between two other users, it only throws exception when the user is not in any conversations yet.

Comment: @DavidBarker I added my create method in the question, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: I can't say it is 100% the problem but you aren't allowing eloquent to manage the relationship. I'll post an answer with a better way to insert the relationship.

Comment: I don't think the problem is from your create method seeing as how your error is from a `select`.  Just a hunch, try `$user = User::find(1); $user->load('conversations');`

Comment: @user1669496 good shout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your class User, add your relation:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    function conversations(){
        return $this->hasMany('Conversation'); 
        //assuming you have a conversation model too
    }

}
```

then you can do this instead:

```
$conversations = Auth::user()->conversations;
```

or to find a specific id:

```
$conversations = User::find($id)->conversations;
```

and you would have all the conversations that are attached to the current user..
after you have got the conversations.. you can check if it's null before doing anything else..
 
(ex: `if(0 < $conversations->count()){ }` )

you can find more info here on the [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

---

**UPDATE:**

can you try this instead?

```
$user = User::has('conversation')->where('user.id','=', $id)->get();
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

```
// get all the conversations connected to the current user
$my_conversations = Auth::user()->conversations;

// generate a list of all the conversation ids 
foreach($my_conversations as $my_conversation) {
    $conversation_ids[] = $my_conversation->id;
}

if(!empty($conversation_ids)) {
    // get all the users for each conversations, via eager loading
    $conversations = Conversation::with('User')
        ->whereIn('id', $conversation_ids)->get();
}
```

Comment: `User::with('conversations')` already assumes there is a `conversations()` method in the model, and as the OP stated it works. This is not a solution.

Comment: "The problem is that when the user does not have any conversations" - that is why you need to get the conversations first and check if there exists any conversation for that user..

Comment: and the user specifically said "How can I test if the user has conversations to avoid this? Thanks in advance.", now what's the problem with that?

Comment: The OP is just eager loading that relationship that shouldn't be throwing the error. The problem isn't with how he is retrieving the related data, eager loading doesn't throw PDO exceptions if there aren't any models to load, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @David Barker do you know what could cause this error then? I have three users for testing users with id 1 and 2 are having a conversation user with id of 3 don't. If I try run it for 1 or 2 it works fine, but for user id of 3 I get that error. If I try to run a user id that doesn't exist I get the exception: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @reiyoushin Thank you for your answer. Your method of testing this does seem to work, but this is running more queries, which I want to avoid. Is there a way to stop the query from throwing an exception if no conversations are found? Why doesn't it just return the user object with user->conversations set to null?

Comment: are you sure you have a user that is logged in? "select * from 
`conversations` where `id` in ()" seems you did not pass an id there.. can you check?

Comment: @mr2_kasper as reijyoushin mentioned above, the lack of id in the IN clause suggests you don't actually have a valid user model loaded through eloquent. If you show us how you save your users and conversations in the question there may be some help to offer.

Comment: @reikyoushin I do have a logged in user and can access its properties via for instance Auth::user()->id or Auth::user()->username and echo it to the screen. I also tried using just the id (3) and it behaves the same, so I do pass the user_id. Also as I mentioned if I pass a user_id that does exist (4) it throws a Trying to get property of non-object exception instead. Could it "get lost" somewhere?

Comment: uhmm just a hunch.. can you try the one i would put in my answer if it will work?

Comment: @mr2_kasper "Also is there a better way to get the array if ids or the users for all these conversations?" i believe `User::has('conversation')->get()` would give you that..

Comment: @reikyoushin I need to get only the users belonging to the conversations the logged in user is in. that is why I the first query, to get those conversations, then I get the users for each of those conversations. Have I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: @mr2_kasper with this setup, you must have at least two ids here for each conversation.. one is the user id of the sender, and another for the user id of the recipient.. did i understood you correctly? and you need to get all users the current user has made contact to (or sent messages with)

Comment: @reikyoushin I have a conversations table, a conversation_user table and a messages table. Users belong to a conversation and messages belong to the conversation as well. The messages only have a sender_id and conversation_id everybody in the conversation can see it. What I'm doing with the code here is making a list of all the conversations the user is in. For each conversation in the list I then want to display the users in that particular conversation. So I need to find the conversations the user is in and then the other users in those. Does it make sense?

Comment: ahh.. so what you need to do is `Conversation::with('user')` instead, in which the conversation list contains the user.id of the current person logged in. right?

Comment: what i'm thinking is get the list of all the conversations the current user has first, then using those conversation ids, get all the users connected to it after.. i'm not sure what better way to do this, but i think that's what you're planning to do..

Comment: @reikyoushin This is pretty much what I'm doing already with slightly different syntax, but same functionality. I found out that it is `$conversations = Conversation::with('User')->whereIn('id', $conversation_ids)->get();` that throws the exception if there are no ids.. kinda makes sense I guess, so the updated solution is correct just need to check the count of $my_conversations also to avoid errors when user has no conversation. You aldready gave the solution to that above though, so I'm making as solved. Thanks a lot for helping out :)

Comment: there, i updated my update _(kinda funny but, well =P)_ so that it includes the check.. good to know you finally got it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you aren't allowing Eloquent to manage the insertion of data across the relationships. Eloquent manages this very easily and would be better to allow it to do this for you, this looks like it may be the source of your problems.

```
public function create($id)
{
    // Use the logged in user or the passed in user ID for user object
    $user = isset($id) ? User::find($id) : Auth::user();

    // Check user exists
    if ( ! $user )
        throw new Exception('User not found');

    // Create a new conversation
    $conversation = new Conversation(array(
        'creator' => $user->id
    ));

    $conversation->save();

    // Attach the user model to the conversation
    // this method will insert all of the relational
    // information into the pivot table for you
    $conversation->users()->attach($user);

    return $conversation;
}
```

Comment: I can see this is a much better way to do it, and that works as well, but it does not solve the problem unfortunately. I still get the same exception. So far I can only avoid it with the if(0 < $conversations->count()){ } ) solution but I want to find out why it throws an exception at all and don't just return null.

Comment: I've just run a test on similar code and I'm just getting empty relationships on the model, no exceptions thrown whether I eager load or not. Let me research a bit, you shouldn't be getting that exception if you're using eloquent properly.

Comment: I added the new create method at the bottom of the question.

Comment: i dont get the -1 on mine when this is not a solution as well.. you made the code cleaner.. yes, but nothing changed much..

Comment: @reikyoushin true, taken the -1 off as you did offer something that does alleviate the problem though there is something deeper that's causing it, that was the initial reason.

Comment: Do you need to see more code to help? I don't know what may be helpful to see though?

Comment: Do you manipulate the relationship anywhere else in your code @mr2_kasper?

Comment: I use it in my view to get the users associated with each conversation. I have updated my question, see at the bottom a possible solution though maybe not the most elegant. That is what I have working now at least. Is there a better way to do this or is using count the best way to check if there are conversations? Also is there a better way to get the array if ids or the users for all these conversations?